# How to break while true loop if the day is today

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, while-loop

I have a python script for exporting some raw data. My goal is to export historical data till today. Here is the piece of code:

```
delta = 0
while True:
    from_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-03-25', '%Y-%m-%d') + datetime.timedelta(days=delta)
    data_date = from_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    if from_date == datetime.date.today():
        break
    delta += 1
```

The problem which I have is that the loop doesn't break when it comes to today. Any idea how to fix it? Or any other way to get the data with the similar approach?

Comment: Have you tried debugging that code? Are `from_date` and `datetime.date.today()` of the same type, so that they can be compared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your break condition will never get true because you compare a datetime object with a date object.

Use the `date()` method to get date from datetime

```
if from_date.date() == datetime.date.today():
    break
```

Comment: @Liu please consider to accept the sollution if this solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could also change the definition of `from_date` to be `date` object and it'll work, but this will require numbers rather than `string`:

```
delta = 0
while True:
    from_date = datetime.date(2018,3,25) + datetime.timedelta(days=delta)
    data_date = from_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    if from_date == datetime.date.today():
        break
    delta += 1
```

With this you can also change the `data_date` definition into:

```
data_date = str(from_date)
```